# Why is the wrap=hard attribute not functioning as expected in a textarea element?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, word-wrap

I do need the line breaks, but even with wrap="hard", defining cols, the value is still a single line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The textarea wrap attribute</h1>

<textarea id="usrtxt" rows="2" cols="5" name="usrtxt" wrap="hard" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; width: 100px;">
At W3Schools you will find free Web-building tutorials.
</textarea>

<!-- A div to display the textarea content -->
<div id="textareaContent"></div>

<script>
// Function to display textarea content
function showTextareaContent() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('usrtxt');
  var displayArea = document.getElementById('textareaContent');
  displayArea.innerText = textarea.value;
}

// Event listener for the textarea input
document.getElementById('usrtxt').addEventListener('input', showTextareaContent);

// Initialize the display area with the current content of the textarea
showTextareaContent();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you need the line-breaks?

Comment: Between the lines. To mimic the visual display of the text in the text area.

Comment: The program-flow is something like: 1. `split('\r\n')` 2. `join('<br>')`.

Comment: Please try the snippet of code, You will see that there is no. \r\n

Comment: Believe.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: There's nothing to believe, just try the snippet, you will see there is no newline there. Or I am really missing where you can see the new line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256854/discussion-between-hamilton-lima-and-deer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#wrap) attribute - the key part is "for form submission".

Indeed the textarea's value does not contain the added `\n`s.

By adding a form element wrapping the textarea, you can use FormData to obtain the formatted text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The textarea wrap attribute</h1>
<form>
<textarea name="usrtxt" id="usrtxt" rows="2" cols="5" name="usrtxt" wrap="hard" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; width: 100px;">
At W3Schools you will find free Web-building tutorials.
</textarea>
</form>
<!-- A div to display the textarea content -->
<div id="textareaContent"></div>

<script>
// Function to display textarea content
function showTextareaContent() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('usrtxt');
  let form = textarea.form;
  let fd = new FormData(form);
  let formatted = fd.get("usrtxt"); // this uses the "name" property of the textarea element
  var displayArea = document.getElementById('textareaContent');
  displayArea.innerText = formatted;
}

// Event listener for the textarea input
document.getElementById('usrtxt').addEventListener('input', showTextareaContent);

// Initialize the display area with the current content of the textarea
showTextareaContent();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me into spacetime Germany 2024. Never heard up till now of `FormData`.  I fiddled a bit https://jsfiddle.net/awp6m1vr/ and came up with `.on('mousemove'...`